# Remove leading zeros from binary conversion

Tags: java, binary, bitwise-operators, leading-zero

What I'm trying to do is convert any number up to 2^32 - 1 that is input by the user to its binary value using only bitwise operators. After much head scratching and tinkering, I've come to this conclusion that seems to be giving me what I want... almost:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
  String input = scan.nextLine();

  int dec = Integer.parseInt(input);

  ArrayList<Integer> binary = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
     if ((dec & 1) == 0) {
        binary.add(0);
     } else {
        binary.add(1);
     }
     dec = dec >>> 1;
  }

  Object[] binaryArray = binary.toArray();

  for (int i = binaryArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     System.out.print(binaryArray[i]);
  }

}
```

Here's my problem now: This does output the proper binary string, but I need to remove the leading zeros so that the decimal number 10 comes out as 1010 in binary rather than 00000000000000000000000000001010.

I'm a first semester CS student, so any help on solving the issue or tips on cleaning up the code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: when you print a digit in binary, try removing that digit from the integer.  What happens to the remaining number?

Comment: Edit: I see you actually are removing the digit by shifting it to the right.  Now the only question is what happens to the variable `dec` when you do that enough times.

Comment: Further commentary: it's wrong to think of an integer like `dec` as "decimal."  All numbers (and strings/letters) in a computer are actually stored in a binary format.  What you're printing now is actually how the number is really formatted inside a computer.

Comment: The binary conversion is already done by `Integer.parseInt(input);`. Everything after it is a complete waste of time and space.

Comment: Assuming you are not handling negative integers, the range is 2^31-1.  See also `Integer.toBinaryString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your code a third time, I noticed something that's a bit tricky.  What you're doing is OK, but there might be a better way.  I'm not going to give the answer, but I want to look at something different.

The `ArrayList` in your code is not needed.  What if you wrote the code this way?

```
  for (int i = 1 << 31; i != 0; i = i >>> 1) {
     if ((dec & i) == 0) {
        System.out.print( "0" );  //binary.add(0);
     } else {
        System.out.print( "1" );  //binary.add(1);
     }
  }
```

Here I simply "print as I go."  The `ArrayList` and the conversion to an array are unneeded.  I've already got one loop working and I don't need to add a second loop to print all the values of the array, because I just use the loop I already have.

OK, so the first bit of code I had was wrong.  It prints in the reverse order.  This code (should! untested!) starts at bit #32 and count *down* from there, printing the bits in order.  It also shows how you can use other things in a `for` loop, like `i = i >>> 1` instead of just always doing `++`.

Elaborating on the hint:  A quick way to "see" what you code is doing is to print important values as your code runs.  For example, to get an idea what you might do with `dec`, add a print statement to print its value.  Some people say to use a debugger and step through code but I find print statements to be faster.

```
     for( int i = 0; i < 32 ; i++ ) {
        if( (dec & 1) == 0 ) {
           binary.add( 0 );
        } else {
           binary.add( 1 );
        }
        dec = dec >>> 1;
        System.out.println( "DEBUG: " + dec );
     }
```

Comment: That’s what I had at first, but it was printing the bits in reverse order. So I added the ArrayList and converted it to an array so I could then print the array in reverse order. That’s the only way I knew I could print the bits the in the correct order. .

Comment: It doesn’t seem to print anything

Comment: @Quaice  That's what I get for not testing.  I used `>` when I should have used `!=`.  It works for me now.

Comment: Same here. Now for the problem of the leading zeros. Is there a way to trim those off to the most significant bit from what we have here? I'm still getting leading zeros up to 32 bits.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on what you mean in your hint? I’m not sure I understand.

Comment: @Quaice OK more hints in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding from your question here is what i can Think of.

If you just want to remove leading zeros using your own approach here is the work around , However i would not recommend you to do that, its bulky and not readable.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    int dec = Integer.parseInt(input);
    ArrayList<Integer> binary = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if ((dec & 1) == 0) {
            binary.add(0);
        } else {
            binary.add(1);
        }
        dec = dec >>> 1;
    }
    StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = binary.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ss.append(binary.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(ss.toString()));
  }
```

Or you can use this approach lesser codes :) easy to read

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    int dec = Integer.parseInt(input);
    char[] arr = Integer.toBinaryString(dec).toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character c : arr) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
  }
```